# How to decode the indexed string param in an event using web3.js?

Tags: javascript, events, blockchain, solidity, web3js

This is the event -

```
    event BridgeAdded(
        string indexed tokenTicker,
        string tokenName,
        string imageUrl
    );
```

I use `web3.eth.abi.decodeParameter("string", topics[1])` to decode the indexed string param but get this error -

```
Error: overflow [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-NUMERIC_FAULT-overflow ] (fault="overflow", operation="toNumber", value="105640063387051144792550451261497903460441457163918809975891088748950929433065", code=NUMERIC_FAULT, version=bignumber/5.6.2)
    at Logger.makeError (/home/rajat/bridge-server/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:233:21)
    at Logger.throwError (/home/rajat/bridge-server/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:242:20)
    at throwFault (/home/rajat/bridge-server/node_modules/@ethersproject/bignumber/lib/bignumber.js:303:19)
    at BigNumber.toNumber (/home/rajat/bridge-server/node_modules/@ethersproject/bignumber/lib/bignumber.js:151:13)
    at /home/rajat/bridge-server/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib/coders/array.js:92:60
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at unpack (/home/rajat/bridge-server/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib/coders/array.js:88:12)
    at TupleCoder.decode (/home/rajat/bridge-server/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib/coders/tuple.js:74:60)
    at AbiCoder.decode (/home/rajat/bridge-server/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib/abi-coder.js:98:22)
    at ABICoder.decodeParametersWith (/home/rajat/bridge-server/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/index.js:310:30)
    at ABICoder.decodeParameters (/home/rajat/bridge-server/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/index.js:291:17)
    at ABICoder.decodeParameter (/home/rajat/bridge-server/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/index.js:280:17)
    at populateDb (/home/rajat/bridge-server/eventListener/main.js:140:36)
    at onEvent (/home/rajat/bridge-server/eventListener/main.js:117:19)
    at handleLogs (/home/rajat/bridge-server/eventListener/main.js:90:32)
    at startListening (/home/rajat/bridge-server/eventListener/main.js:64:27) {
  reason: 'overflow',
  code: 'NUMERIC_FAULT',
  fault: 'overflow',
  operation: 'toNumber',
  value: '105640063387051144792550451261497903460441457163918809975891088748950929433065'
}
```

Please help me resolve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `decodeLog` instead, and you would also need The ABI byte code in the `data` field of `logs` (if you can get the `topics` array you should get `data` from `logs` as well):

```
let result = web3.eth.abi.decodeLog([{
    type: 'string',
    name: 'tokenTicker',
    indexed: true
    }],
    data,
    topics[1]);
```

But you would get the hash of the value of `tokenTicker` because it is indexed. This is because. `If the index parameter is a string, bytes or array than the keccak-256 hash of is the topic instead.` So you can't really retrieve the indexed string value. I found this out in the following way:

I deployed a contract in `Rinkeby` that has a simple function that emit the `BridgeAdded`:
[image]

I called the above function ([Here is the TX](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x55e880cda6f1223541f84109bbdb78b188a28b87c096d85b82584ef3458f2c49)) and then I try to decode the event with web3 js. As you would see, it would return the `keccak256` hash of the indexed string:

[image]

Even in [Etherscan](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xee80053f81c312ad2a8e79345e05704d35192026#events) you can see its not able to decode the indexed string:

[image]

So there might be two workaround options I can think of:

Option 1: Create an index with primitive type instead of indexing string:

```
event BridgeAdded(
        uint256 indexed id,
        string tokenTicker,
        string tokenName,
        string imageUrl
    );
```

Option 2: You can create another string that holds the exact same value as the indexed string:

```
event BridgeAdded(
            string indexed indexedTokenTicker,
            string tokenTicker,
            string tokenName,
            string imageUrl
        );
```

Comment: I did this but the decoded form of the `string indexed` param is still in hex format. It looks like this - 
`tokenTicker: '0x56a4db8db8d4f3dc22c02e5cd25b4bb01274bb7d3f0a5695df5ab5a544f3c0fe'`

Is there any way I can convert this to readable string format?

Comment: Okay so I just found out "If the index parameter is a string, bytes or array than the keccak-256 hash of is the topic instead." So if you index with a string, array or bytes you can never retrieve that particular event...I have shown the detailed explanation in the answer. I had also suggested two workarounds at the end.

Comment: @Tahlil could you please give us a reference why is it impossible to retrive that event